# Oracle Create Function

Tags: oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql

I tried to create an Oracle function where table name, column name and where string are dynamic parameters:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION MYSCHEMA.myFunctionName( 
  tableName in nvarchar2,
  columnName in nvarchar2,
  whereStr in nvarchar2)
RETURN nvarchar2

IS nActive nvarchar2(2000);

BEGIN
  declare 
  querystr nvarchar2(2000) ;
  result nvarchar2(2000);
  begin
    querystr :='
    select  listagg('+columnName+','+','+') within group (order by '+columnName+')
    from '+tableName+' where  1 = 1 '+whereStr+';';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE querystr
    INTO result;
       nActive := result;
          RETURN ( nActive );
  end;
END ;
/
```

But it gives me error "Warning: compiled but with compilation errors".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use `show errors` or query the `user_errors` view to see the actual compilation errors. (SQL Developer also has a pane that shows them). You need to look at unescaped quotes within your dynamic string and the concatentation character (`||` not `+`); but why does your listagg have three arguments?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. For concatenate strings in `Oracle` use `||` not `+`
2. You don't need `;` at the end of `execute immediate` query string
3. You need to escape `'` using `''`.

... as @Aleksej said

4. `Execute immediate` need query string in `CHAR or VARCHAR2`;
5. `listagg` return either `raw` or `VARCHAR2`

---

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION MYSCHEMA.myFunctionName( 
  tableName in varchar2,
  columnName in varchar2,
  whereStr in varchar2)
RETURN varchar2
BEGIN
  declare 
  querystr varchar2(2000) ;
  result varchar2(2000);
  begin
    querystr :='
    select  listagg('|| columnName || ', '','') within group (order by ' ||columnName ||')
    from ' || tableName || ' where  1 = 1 ' || whereStr;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE querystr INTO result;
    return result;
  end;
END ;
/
```

Comment: Thanks buddy...True query is CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION name( 
tableName in varchar2,
columnName in varchar2,
whereStr in varchar2)
RETURN varchar2
IS nActive varchar2(2000);
BEGIN
declare 
querystr varchar2(2000) ;
result VARCHAR2(2000);
begin
querystr :='
    select  listagg('|| columnName || ', '','') within group (order by ' ||columnName ||')
    from ' || tableName || ' where  1 = 1 ' || whereStr;
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE querystr
INTO result;
 nActive := result;
  RETURN ( nActive );
end;
END ;
/

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the type of your variables, considering that

- "The return data type is RAW if the measure column is RAW; otherwise the return value is VARCHAR2" ([documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030))
- [EXECUTE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems017.htm) needs a VARCHAR2: "It must be of type CHAR or VARCHAR2, not NCHAR or NVARCHAR2"

So:

```
declare 
  querystr varchar2(2000) ;
  result VARCHAR2(32767);
begin
  ...
```